# Is the configuration in the log4j2.xml file overrided by using the programmatic configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, log4j2, cross-cutting-concerns

I want to override some configuration programmatically for the default in my common library that should be automatically loaded by other spring boot application loading it.
How should I approach it.
What I have tried is

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
public class CustomConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {
static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        builder.setConfigurationName(name);
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).
                addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").
                addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
                addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t]"));
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY,
                Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG).
                add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).
                addAttribute("additivity", false));
        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(),null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[] {"*"};
    }
}
```

But it is not loading the configuration automatically
Any help will be appreciated.